# Discrete data plots in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have two data arrays and I am looking to plot them in a single plot using `matplotlib`

The data arrays are:

```
date_array=['2018-03-26', '2018-03-27', '2018-03-28', '2018-03-29', '2018-04-02', '2018-04-03', '2018-04-04', '2018-04-05', '2018-04-06', '2018-04-09', '2018-04-10', '2018-04-11', '2018-04-12', '2018-04-13', '2018-04-16', '2018-04-17', '2018-04-18', '2018-04-19', '2018-04-20', '2018-04-23', '2018-04-24', '2018-04-25', '2018-04-26', '2018-04-27', '2018-04-30', '2018-05-01', '2018-05-02', '2018-05-03', '2018-05-04', '2018-05-07', '2018-05-08', '2018-05-09', '2018-05-10', '2018-05-11', '2018-05-14', '2018-05-15', '2018-05-16', '2018-05-17', '2018-05-18', '2018-05-21', '2018-05-22', '2018-05-23', '2018-05-24', '2018-05-25', '2018-05-29', '2018-05-30', '2018-05-31', '2018-06-01', '2018-06-04', '2018-06-05', '2018-06-06', '2018-06-07', '2018-06-08', '2018-06-11', '2018-06-12', '2018-06-13', '2018-06-14', '2018-06-15', '2018-06-18', '2018-06-19', '2018-06-20', '2018-06-21', '2018-06-22', '2018-06-25', '2018-06-26', '2018-06-27', '2018-06-28', '2018-06-29', '2018-07-02', '2018-07-03', '2018-07-05', '2018-07-06', '2018-07-09', '2018-07-10', '2018-07-11', '2018-07-12', '2018-07-13', '2018-07-16', '2018-07-17', '2018-07-18', '2018-07-19', '2018-07-20', '2018-07-23', '2018-07-24', '2018-07-25', '2018-07-26', '2018-07-27', '2018-07-30', '2018-07-31', '2018-08-01', '2018-08-02', '2018-08-03', '2018-08-06', '2018-08-07', '2018-08-08', '2018-08-09', '2018-08-10', '2018-08-13', '2018-08-14', '2018-08-15']

value_1 = [45.27, 44.53, 44.68, 45.29, 44.43, 44.88, 45.85, 45.7, 44.76, 44.22, 44.81, 44.54, 44.13, 44.0, 43.41, 43.68, 43.29, 42.33, 42.18, 41.8, 41.78, 42.46, 43.67, 43.92, 44.75, 44.33, 44.41, 45.7, 43.8, 44.16, 44.9, 45.07, 46.24, 48.3, 49.21, 49.84, 50.34, 50.4, 49.98, 50.7, 49.15, 48.5, 48.53, 47.65, 48.52, 47.36, 46.13, 46.01, 47.27, 48.04, 49.48, 49.96, 50.48, 51.3, 52.29, 51.86, 50.2, 49.42, 50.0, 52.42, 52.32, 52.62, 52.13, 51.13, 50.24, 48.66, 48.99, 48.05, 48.33, 49.22, 50.62, 51.39, 51.87, 47.37, 49.53, 49.54, 51.82, 51.65, 52.98, 52.09, 54.24, 53.98, 52.72, 51.09, 49.99, 48.55, 47.98, 48.67, 48.87, 48.45, 48.65, 50.06, 52.64, 54.6, 56.61, 55.77, 55.59, 56.5, 56.31, 54.0]

value_2 = [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 95.39398869716304, 95.39398869716304, 0, 0, 95.39398869716304, 95.39398869716304, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 95.39398869716304]
```

The thing is that I have data points available for `value_1` for all `dates` in `date_array` but not for `value_2` so wherever I don't have the value available I have filled in a zero (That is one of my question as you'll see later).

When I plot it using this code:

```
x = date_array
y1 = value_1
y2 = value_2
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.scatter(x, y1, s=10, c='b', marker="s", label='fig 1')
ax1.scatter(x,y2, s=10, c='r', marker="o", label='fig 2')
plt.legend(loc='upper left');
plt.show()
```

I get this:

[image]

My questions:

1. How do I work my around the fact that I don't have all values available for `value_2` and still get the plot? I don't want the red dots to show that have value `0` in the plot but am not sure how I'll get around to do that. **Note** An entry in `value_2` can't have 0 value so if it is 0 that means its not present.
2. How to fix the messed up data labels on x-axis? If there are only 10-12 markers on the x-axis that would look neater.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the `zero`s to `NaN` and they wont be plotted:

```
value_2 = [np.nan if x==0 else x for x in value_2]
```

For the second questions, I would transform to `datetime` object and the distance is adjusted automatically(and after rotate them):

```
from datetime import datetime
date_array = [datetime.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%d').date() for i in date_array]
plt.xticks(rotation=70)
```

Complete code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime
date_array = [datetime.strptime(i, '%Y-%m-%d').date() for i in date_array]
value_2 = [np.nan if x==0 else x for x in value_2]
x = date_array
y1 = value_1
y2 = value_2
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)
ax1.plot_date(x, y1, c='b', label='fig 1')
ax1.plot_date(x, y2, c='r', label='fig 2')
plt.legend(loc='upper left')
plt.xticks(rotation=70)
plt.show()
```

[image]